# determine the value of theta and alpha.

Tags: trigonometry

If $\tan^2\theta = 1 = 1 + \tan^2\alpha$.

Prove that $\sin^2\theta = \frac 12  (1 + \sin^2\alpha$)

Help appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT:**

The given equation imply $$\tan^2 \alpha=1-1=0 \implies \sin \alpha =0$$

also $$\tan^2\theta=1 \implies \sin^2 \theta = \cos^2 \theta$$ or $$\sin^2 \theta-\cos^2 \theta=0$$

which further implies either $$\sin \theta+\cos \theta=0$$

or$$\sin \theta-\cos \theta=0$$

which gives $$\sin \theta=\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt2}$$ or equivalently $$\sin^2\theta=\frac1{2}$$

Use all this to conclude

Answer (score 0):

$1=1+\tan ^2\alpha$ implies $\tan ^2\alpha=0$ and so $\sin ^2\alpha=0$; $1=\tan ^2\theta$ implies $\cos ^2\theta=\sin ^2\theta$. Therefore, $\sin ^2\theta=\frac12$, because $\cos ^2\theta + \sin ^2\theta=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Split it into two equations. Now, for the first one:
$$
1 = \tan^2\theta= \frac{\sin^2\theta}{\cos^2 \theta} \quad \implies \quad \sin^2 \theta= \cos^2 \theta
$$
If two squares equal, then the base numbers are either equal, or eachother's negative. $\sin\theta $ and $\cos\theta$ are only ever equal or the negative of one another when $\theta$ is $45^\circ$ off from the axes. It is known that the sine of such an angle is $\pm\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}$, so squaring gives $\sin^2 \theta = \frac{1}{2}$.

The second equation:
$$
1 = 1 + \tan^2 \alpha \quad \implies \quad \frac{\sin^2 \alpha}{\cos^2 \alpha} = 0
$$
so $\sin^2 \alpha$ has to be equal to $0$. Now we can confirm that $\sin^2 \theta = \frac{1}{2}$ is indeed equal to $\frac{1}{2}(1 + \sin^2 \alpha) = \frac{1}{2}(1 + 0) = \frac{1}{2}$.